# Posting an array of byte arrays with web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

With .NET web api, we need to post an array of byte arrays.  So...

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] List<byte[]> documents)
```

`documents` is pulled from the body.

Is it possible to POST FromBody an array of byte arrays?

I know in JSON we can have...

```
[
    "base64 encoded document 1 contents",
    "base64 encoded document 2 contents"
]
```

Would the only option to base64 encode each document? This would give a signature of...

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] List<byte[]> documents)
```

Comment: When you Base64 encode a byte array, the result is a String. The controller would accept a String input for one document, or an array of String for multiple documents. The controller would Base64 decode the string into a byte array.

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured. Our preference is to post byte[] but since we have a list of them, base64 is probably the only way we can go.

Comment: Base64 is the only way to go with byte[]'s moving across HTTP, there will be controller characters in the bytes that will corrupt the  message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@lcryder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281882/lcryder) answered the question in the comments:

> When you Base64 encode a byte array, the result is a String. The
>   controller would accept a String input for one document, or an array
>   of String for multiple documents. The controller would Base64 decode
>   the string into a byte array.

and

> Base64 is the only way to go with byte[]'s moving across HTTP, there
>   will be controller characters in the bytes that will corrupt the
>   message.